# Send Tab to other device with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-tabs, google-sync, firefox-sync

Firefox has a useful feature of sending tabs to another device. It will cause some sort of reminder, when the browser is next opened on the targetted synchronized device.

Is there anything similar with Chrome? Note that I am specifically asking for a solution that active reminds me about the tab on a specific device; Anything that requires me to actively look up a list, or doesn't separate by device, isn't applicable.

---

With Chrome, as far as I know, I only get options that are not device-specific, and/or require me to actively look up if there are any such saved tabs.

- Adding as a bookmark.
- Access through "tabs from other devices".
- External solutions such as Pocket or sending an Email to myself.

Use cases include:

- A discussion, I want to comment on, while reading on a mobile device. Answering is best handled by pushing that URL to my home PC.
- An interesting-looking webcomic while doing something on PC or smartphone. I want this to show up when I pick up my tablet in the evening.

---

I would consider just using Firefox for this feature. Sadly, part of my usage involves editing bookmarks and bookmark folders, and Firefox for iOS falls badly short in that regard. Delegating these steps to a different device would be a worse compromise than not having the send-to-device feature.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome recently added a flag (chrome://flags/#enable-send-tab-to-self) to support this, albeit primitive compared to Firefox so far (you can't choose which device it gets sent to).

[This story](https://www.chromestory.com/2019/03/send-to-my-devices/) said it started working March 12 2019, but one of the comments in the story said there was a long delay before he/she saw the tab sent. When I tested it, the feature didn't seem to be working yet. I waited a few minutes, maybe I didn't wait long enough.

Comment: The story also mentions *“Allows users to push tabs from Android devices to other synced devices”*. Which would be more of a subset implementation. Android-to-other-devices is useful, but more frequently I need PC-to-iOS or PC-to-PC. Sadly, that latter part is where Pushbullet fails too...

Comment: True. It's one of things that keeps me coming back to Firefox -- you can send tabs to any synced device (actually even lower than that -- I can choose between Firefox or Firefox Developer or Firefox Beta, etc on the same device).

Comment: Sadly, Firefox has heavily subpar bookmark management on mobile, especially iOS, so subjectively I'd be switching a minor issue for a major issue.